# family_name and given_name not included in AzureAD token claims

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, identityserver4

I have successfully connected an OIDC flow with AzureAD, but unfortunately I'm unable to get `family_name` and `given_name` claims included in the token. I am requesting the following scopes: `{ "openid", "profile", "email", "offline_access" }`

In the Azure App Registration page I have added the `family_name` and `given_name` to the manifest under `optionalClaims` both in `idToken` and `accessToken`, and even set them as essential - but they're still not being returned:

```
"optionalClaims": {
        "idToken": [
            {
                "name": "email",
                "source": null,
                "essential": false,
                "additionalProperties": []
            },
            {
                "name": "family_name",
                "source": null,
                "essential": true,
                "additionalProperties": []
            },
            {
                "name": "given_name",
                "source": null,
                "essential": true,
                "additionalProperties": []
            }
        ],
        "accessToken": [
            {
                "name": "email",
                "source": null,
                "essential": false,
                "additionalProperties": []
            },
            {
                "name": "family_name",
                "source": null,
                "essential": true,
                "additionalProperties": []
            },
            {
                "name": "given_name",
                "source": null,
                "essential": true,
                "additionalProperties": []
            }
```

[This Microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims#v20-specific-optional-claims-set) says "These claims are always included in v1.0 Azure AD tokens, but not included in v2.0 tokens unless requested".

I'm using v2 and so I've also tried adding `family_name` and `given_name` to the scopes that I'm requesting in my OIDC call, but it fails and says those scopes don't exist.

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler:
> 'invalid_client', error_description: 'AADSTS650053: The application 'REMOVED' asked for scope 'given_name' that doesn't exist on the resource '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'.

Any suggestions on how I can get AzureAD to include those claims for me?

Comment: Those **aren't "scopes"** to ask for - those are additional claims .... so you cannot include those in the list of **scopes** when you make the call - that's what the error tells you

Answer (score 1):

In azure ad app registration , I have following optional claims added:

[image]

Manifest:

```
"optionalClaims": {
        "idToken": [],
        "accessToken": [
            {
                "name": "upn",
                "source": null,
                "essential": false,
                "additionalProperties": []
            },
            {
                "name": "family_name",
                "source": null,
                "essential": false,
                "additionalProperties": []
            },
            {
                "name": "given_name",
                "source": null,
                "essential": false,
                "additionalProperties": []
            },
```

[image]

***I recieved the error:***
`AADSTS650053%3a+The+application+%27kavyarepo%27+asked+for+scope+%27given_name%27+that+doesn%27t+exist+on+the+resource+%2xxx0-000000000000%27.+Contact+the+app+vendor.%0d%0a`

When i gave scope as `given_name`

[image]

**It must be either** `api://clientid/given_name` or `api://clinetid/.default` .

But generally users profile can be fetched with microsoft graph permissions:

**check below steps:**

***With authorize endpoint:*** **`https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`** and client credentials,

and ***scope for microsoft graph***, i.e; **`https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`**
Received code with below endpoint after the user logged in:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/x/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?Client_id=xxxd-xx350c02de9247&client_secret="sdxxx"&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default&grant_type=authorization_code&response_type=code
```

Then after, I used the code in token endpoint to receive access token :

**`https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx/oauth2/v2.0/token?Client_id=9xx-4xxx7&client_secret=”xxx”&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default&code=””`**

[image]

When decoded the token at https://jwt.ms, received the claims along with optional claims

[image]

**Make sure the scopes include: **profile User.Read** **openid** **email** which are microsoft graph permissions.**

These should be granted admin consent to user while authenticating or through the portal:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's a good option to be able to fetch the data through Microsoft Graph, but ultimately I figured out the claims WERE in the token issued by the OIDC flow, I was just inspecting the final token issued by my local identity server instead of the intermediary token issued by AzureAD.

Answer (score 0):

The `family_name` and `given_name` claims actually **were being included in the token issued by AzureAD** - I was only inspecting the final token issued by my local identity server.

When I debugged the Callback method and inspected the AzureAD token, not the final token issued locally, I could access the claims from there.